# SQLAlchemy Subquery Executes But Does Nothing

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a filter on my right hand items before applying a left outer join in SQLAlchemy and for some reason the subquery seems to have no effect.

First, I know I should bet back 12 results from my join:

```
startTimestampString = "2020-05-15T17:25:55"
itemRows = Item.query.filter(Item.timestamp > startTimestampString).all()
print(f"target # itemRows: {len(itemRows)}")
# target # itemRows: 12
```

But when I actually apply the subquery in my join, I get back all 575 items from the right hand side of the join instead:

```
subq = Item.query.filter(Item.timestamp > startTimestampString).subquery()
statusRows = Status.query.outerjoin(subq, Status.serviceID == subq.c.serviceID)\
print(f"returned # of subquery item rows: {sum([len(row.items) for row in statusRows])}")
# returned # of subquery item rows: 575
```

What am I doing wrong here to make the subquery not actually apply any filtering?

---

Also some version info FWIW:

```
$ pip3 list|grep alchemy
Flask-SQLAlchemy       2.4.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.21.0
SQLAlchemy             1.3.12
SQLAlchemy-JSONField   0.9.0
SQLAlchemy-Utils       0.36.1
```

And I'm connecting to my DB via `postgresql+psycopg2` so that version:

```
$ pip3 list|grep psy
psycopg2-binary        2.8.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell the ORM that you are eagerly loading a filtered set of items from a subquery using a join:

```
subq = Item.query.filter(Item.timestamp > startTimestampString).subquery()
item_alias = db.aliased(Item, subq)
statusRows = Status.query.\
    outerjoin(item_alias, Status.serviceID == item_alias.serviceID).\
    options(db.contains_eager(Status.items, alias=item_alias))
```

Without `contains_eager()` accessing `items` relationship attribute of `Status` will in its default configuration fetch the full set of items.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this ORM stuff and didn't know about that option. :-)